# Java [android]: should I used synchronized ou semphore object?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have 2 threads.

The first one calls this function

```
public int doCompute1(obj)
{
    if (obj.state == OK_FOR_COMPUTE1)
    {
      // do something
      obj.state = OK_FOR_COMPUTE2;
    }
}
```

The second thread calls this function

```
public int doCompute2(obj)
{
    if (obj.state == OK_FOR_COMPUTE2)
    {
      // do something
      obj.state = OK_FOR_COMPUTE1;
    }
}
```

For the moment it seems to work perfectly !

My question is: Is it correct ?
Is it possible that on multicore processor, obj.state is in cache memory and then modifiyng this vaue by a thread, wouldn't be visible by the second thread?

What should I do if this code is not correct?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean == in the if statements.

Comment: yes. sorry. I've made the correction

Comment: ok. But if the final answer is in the comment ! Should I Accept the answer or not ? What should I Do in this case ! Finally may question hav had a response !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
synchronized(obj){  
    if (...){ 
    }
}
```

will do the stuff

EDIT:

What synchronized do?

```
synchronized(obj){  //if obj is not locked,i lock it and go to the if instruction.if obj is locked, i'm waiting for its unlocking

          //some stuff that will run with no thread-interruption caused by other synchronized block locked on the obj object 

    }//the obj object is unlocked and let other methods enter their synchronized(obj) block
```

Comment: Hum. Ok thank's but what really happened when I'm doing that ! should I synchronised All the object or synchronized only obj.state ?

Comment: You have to synchronized an object shared by all the methods you want to run synchronously.
See my edited answer where i explain how synchronized works

Comment: hum Ok I understand. This is not the obj I used in my code this a another object ! But using synchronized will not resolve my problem ! my both thread can't acces to the same function ! thread #1 call doCompute1 and thread #2 call doCompute2. synchonized will then not be usefull ! My problem is a processor cache problem !

Comment: if you synchronized two methods with the same object instance it's ok.

Comment: ah ok.in fact `synchronised` create a semaphore

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, I haven't be clear enough ! My question was not "How to prevent concurrent access to a object method". My question was "If I change a variable form a thread, can I be sure another thread will see the modified value ?"

Comment: yes, the OS will invalidate the variable in the others CPU cache if they don't use the same

Comment: ok thank you. so my code is valid like it is actually. That explain why it's works on all devices I tested !